# How can I stop my page from scrolling when I annotate on a touch device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

The problem is on this page: http://www.tagalogreader.com/document.php?id=28.

I'm using this: https://github.com/aron/annotator.touch.js with this https://github.com/openannotation/annotator.

There is one annoying bug that I have found when using my ipad. When I highlight some text and then click "annotate" the box pops up to write a note. That is desired. But what happens next is that somehow I'm automatically scrolled to the middle of the article even though I was highlighting something in the beginning of the article. So I just have to scroll back up.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue to your question.  As it stands, there is not enough information to provide an answer to your question.

Comment: Try to isolate whether this has anything to do with annotator or the annotator touch plugin, first. Inspect the CSS of the pop-up, see whether your version of iOS + Safari might have any known issues. One thought is that changing keyboard focus to the editor might have some problems due to Safari trying to maintain the scroll position and the editor having a fixed position.

Comment: I get a 404 on your example page.

Comment: Yeah, this really sucks. I have another question going to figure that out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059640/why-does-my-openshift-site-say-welcome-to-firebase-hosting

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plugin that disables the scrollbar when Annotator Editor is shown:

```
/**
* Annotator Plugin to diasble scrollbar when Editor is shown
*/
Annotator.Plugin.DisableScroll = function (element, options) {
  var myPlugin = {};
  myPlugin.pluginInit = function () {
    // This annotator instance
    this.annotator
        .subscribe("annotationEditorShown", function (editor, annotation) {
          $(window).disablescroll();
        })
        .subscribe("annotationEditorHidden", function (editor) {
          $(window).disablescroll("undo");
        })
  };
  return myPlugin;
};
```

It depends on the jQuery [Plugin](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll) written by [Josh Harrison](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll).

**Usage:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#content').annotator().annotator('addPlugin', 'DisableScroll');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/saratucapa/1/edit?js,output