# Why does my openshift site say "Welcome to Firebase Hosting"?

Tags: firebase, openshift

I haven't made any changes to the code, but now my site (http://www.tagalogreader.com/) says "Welcome to Firebase Hosting".

Have I been hacked? What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but I can tell you that you're definitively not seeing content served by Firebase Hosting (it's HTTPS only and the DNS records appear to be pointing at Amazon EC2). The content you're seeing is auto-generated by the Firebase CLI for a new project, but is just an HTML file that can be deployed anywhere.

Comment: All other content on my site is 404.

Answer (score 1):

This is the page you get when you create a [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) website, but have not hosted any content.

If you are using Firebase go [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) to host your content.

If not go to your domain provider and check your records, if you see anything with firebase in it get rid of it and update it to what it should be

Comment: I didn't create a firebase website. I guess my domain provider account was hacked. I'm looking into it.

Comment: I removed the following: An SPF record including _spf.firebasemail.com, a TXT record with content "firebase=tagalog-reader", and a DKIM key for host "smtpapi._domainkey". Would those cause the problem? My provider says they have been there since May. But this problem just showed up today.

Comment: There should also be one that looks like this "globalsign-domain-verification=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you( or your client has changed the `nameserver`s ) of you domain...

Your website is no more linked to the nameserver it used to query earlier...

If that doesn't help check out your `A` and `CNAME` records... They might be pointing to firebase servers.

And that is probably the servers default page you are seeing, so doesn't look like it's hacked :)